# accessing protected data members of another class

Tags: c++, protected, private-members, red-black-tree

I am trying to implement a red-black tree, and I have created nodes that each contain a left child node, right child node, and a parent node, stored as protected data members in my redBlackNode class. In my insert function, I need to access each nodes protected members like its left child or its parent, using node->_left->_parent and so on. But, my compiler complains that

```
bst.h:77:29: error: ‘Node<int, int>* Node<int, int>::_left’ is protected
rbbst.h:160:3: error: within this context
bst.h:77:46: error: ‘Node<int, int>* Node<int, int>::_parent’ is protected
rbbst.h:160:3: error: within this context
```

How can i overcome this issue?

Comment: Are you familiar with [accessors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessor)? The Node could reveal to others where its neighbors are.

Comment: Either provide public accessors or add a friend declaration for the other class or function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my suggestions :
1. recode the class node as  a struct;
2. add accessible pubilic member funs that  return reference to those data members and you should 
   put the data member as private;

Finally, forgive my poor English.
It's my first answer on this web.(●'◡'●)

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare a specific function to have access to a class's private members by using the "friend" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Are you subclassing the main class. Remeber that in inheritance is C++ only subclasses can access protected protocols. Clearing that out try making the methods public. Please show the error lines and the code for more help.